# updated environment in anaconda and now kernel dies and "code will never be executed"

Tags: python-3.x, image, kernel, anaconda, gensim

I set up an environment in anaconda for running gensim. it's been working great. today I updated gensim and some other packages in the environment. Now I get the following error in the terminal window. in my jupyter notebook, the kernel dies and it can't be restarted and when I try to import gensim it says module not found. I can't figure out where to start or what went wrong. I've been writing code for weeks and everything has been hunky-dory until i updated. any clues what to do?

Why will some code never be executed and what is "image" and why can't it find it?

Here is the complete terminal output for the failed session:

```
Last login: Fri Mar  9 13:11:37 on ttys000
GWSB-FUN304-M1:~ dlhoffman$ /Users/dlhoffman/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool ; exit;
[I 13:11:41.634 NotebookApp] JupyterLab alpha preview extension loaded from /Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab
JupyterLab v0.27.0
Known labextensions:
[I 13:11:41.636 NotebookApp] Running the core application with no additional extensions or settings
[I 13:11:41.640 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/dlhoffman
[I 13:11:41.640 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 13:11:41.640 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/?token=cb91dc32623736db4e7cf2baedee4284f4d3adc00cdf9f5c
[I 13:11:41.640 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 13:11:41.644 NotebookApp] 

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=cb91dc32623736db4e7cf2baedee4284f4d3adc00cdf9f5c
[I 13:11:41.758 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1
[I 13:12:06.185 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 38a44a07-dfc6-4e61-8a69-df62ddc60d46
/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cffi/__pycache__/_cffi_ext.c:239:3: warning: 
      code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
  _cffi_check__zmq_msg_t(0);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cffi/__pycache__/_cffi_ext.c:272:3: warning: 
      code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
  _cffi_check__zmq_pollitem_t(0);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 warnings generated.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 18, in <module>
    import jupyter_client
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/connect.py", line 22, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/utils/sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/select.py", line 26, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/error.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libsodium.23.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/libzmq.5.dylib
  Reason: image not found
[I 13:12:09.186 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 18, in <module>
    import jupyter_client
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/connect.py", line 22, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/utils/sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/select.py", line 26, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/error.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libsodium.23.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/libzmq.5.dylib
  Reason: image not found
[I 13:12:12.194 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 18, in <module>
    import jupyter_client
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/connect.py", line 22, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/utils/sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/select.py", line 26, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/error.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libsodium.23.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/libzmq.5.dylib
  Reason: image not found
[I 13:12:15.202 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 18, in <module>
    import jupyter_client
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/connect.py", line 22, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/utils/sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/select.py", line 26, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/error.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libsodium.23.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/libzmq.5.dylib
  Reason: image not found
[W 13:12:16.348 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 38a44a07-dfc6-4e61-8a69-df62ddc60d46
[I 13:12:18.210 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5)
kernel 38a44a07-dfc6-4e61-8a69-df62ddc60d46 restarted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 18, in <module>
    import jupyter_client
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/connect.py", line 22, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/utils/sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/select.py", line 26, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/error.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libsodium.23.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/dlhoffman/anaconda3/lib/libzmq.5.dylib
  Reason: image not found
[W 13:12:21.219 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 13:12:21.219 NotebookApp] Kernel 38a44a07-dfc6-4e61-8a69-df62ddc60d46 died, removing from map.
kernel 38a44a07-dfc6-4e61-8a69-df62ddc60d46 restarted failed!
[W 13:12:21.232 NotebookApp] Kernel deleted before session
[W 13:12:21.233 NotebookApp] 410 DELETE /api/sessions/b337ffd0-4c75-4d57-bb97-279e3a377e2d (::1) 1.80ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Dropbox/_Tom%20and%20Donna/_Jupyter%20Donna/Donna%20pre-process%20the%20IFTTT%20data.ipynb
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to remove everything and re-install. You likely have some dependencies that need to be updated.

In my case, I just had to update zeromq and libsodium

```
conda update zeromq libsodium
```

Answer (score 0):

I showed the terminal message to a software engineer and he said WTF so I deleted the environment and reinstalled everything and now it works again. I guess this is the more sophisticated version of "when it doubt, reboot."